# C#: Using Directory.GetFiles to get files with fixed length

Tags: c#, .net, windows, filenames, long-filenames

The directory 'C:\temp' has two files named 'GZ96A7005.tif' and 'GZ96A7005001.tif'. They have different length with the same extension. Now I run below code:

```
string[] resultFileNames = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\temp", "????????????.tif");
```

The 'resultFileNames' return two items 'c:\temp\GZ96A7005.tif' and 'c:\temp\GZ96A7005001.tif'.
But the Window Search will work fine. This is why and how do I get I want?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know I've read about this somewhere before, but the best I could find right now was this reference to it in [Raymond Chen's blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2007/12/17/6785519.aspx). The point is that Windows keeps a short (8.3) filename for every file with a long filename, for backward compatibility, and filename **wildcards are matched against both the long and short filenames**. You can see these short filenames by opening a command prompt and running "`dir /x`". Normally, getting a list of files which match `????????.tif` (8) returns a list of file with 8 or less characters in their filename and a .tif extension. But **every file with a long filename also has a short filename with 8.3 characters, so they all match this filter**.

In your case both `GZ96A7005.tif` and `GZ96A7005001.tif` are long filenames, so they both have a 8.3 short filename which matches `????????.tif` (anything with 8 or more `?`'s).

UPDATE... from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f.aspx):

> Because this method checks against
>   file names with both the 8.3 file name
>   format and the long file name format,
>   a search pattern similar to "`*1*.txt`"
>   may return unexpected file names. For
>   example, using a search pattern of
>   "`*1*.txt`" returns "`longfilename.txt`"
>   because the equivalent 8.3 file name
>   format is "`LONGFI~1.TXT`".

---

UPDATE: The MSDN docs specifiy different behavior for the "`?`" wildcard in Directory.GetFiles() and DirectoryInfo.GetFiles(). The documentation seems to be wrong, however. See [Matthew Flaschen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/963279/c-using-directory-getfiles-to-get-files-with-fixed-length/963289#963289).

Answer (score 7):

For [Directory.GetFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f.aspx), ? signifies "Exactly zero *or* one character."  On the other hand, you could use [DirectoryInfo.GetFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8he88b63.aspx), for which ? signifies "Exactly one character" (apparently what you want).

EDIT:

Full code:

```
string[] resultFileNames = (from fileInfo in new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\temp").GetFiles("????????????.tif") select fileInfo.Name).ToArray();
```

You can probably skip the ToArray and just let resultFileNames be an `IEnumerable<string>`.

People are reporting this doesn't work for them on MS .NET.  The below exact code works for me with on Mono on Ubuntu Hardy.  I agree it doesn't really *make sense* to have two related classes use different conventions.  However, that is what the documentation (linked above) says, and Mono complies with the docs.  If Microsoft's implementation doesn't, they have a bug:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

public class GetFiles
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string[] resultFileNames = (from fileInfo in new DirectoryInfo(@".").GetFiles("????????????.tif") select fileInfo.Name).ToArray();
        foreach(string fileName in resultFileNames)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(fileName);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But 'DirectoryInfo.GetFiles' also returns two items 'c:\temp\GZ96A7005.tif' and 'c:\temp\GZ96A7005001.tif'.

Comment: Leon, can you post the exact code you're using with DirectoryInfo.GetFiles?

Comment: DirectoryInfo.GetFiles() matches zero or one character for me. .NET 3.5 SP1. Maybe that behavior was a bug in previous versions. Certainly doesn't make sense for them to behave differently.

Comment: Lucas, I replied in my answer.  Please look at the docs I linked.

Comment: You are right that the docs specify different behavior for "?" in both methods. However, I tested this in MS.NET and they both behave the same way (matches zero or one character). It is also this way in Win32 APIs, so it must be a documentation error.

Answer (score 1):

The ? character matches "zero or one" characters... so from what you have I would imagine that your search pattern will match any file ending in ".tif" that is between zero and twelve characters long.

Try dropping another file in that is only three characters long with a ".tif" extension and see if the code picks that up as well. I have a sneaking suspicion that it will ;)

As far as the Windows search is concerned, it is most definately not using the same algorithm under the hood. The ? character might have a very different meaning there than it does in the .Net search pattern specification for the Directory.GetFiles(string, string) method.

Answer (score 0):

```
string path = "C:/";
var files = Directory.GetFiles(path)
    .Where(f => f.Replace(path, "").Length == 8);
```

A little costly with the string replacement. You can add whatever extension you need.

Comment: You should use Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension() instead of Replace()

Comment: @Lucas perhaps you should show a working example so that we can up vote Yuriy answer